# Sliding Full width div in CSS Or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking around the internet for a while to find a good library or way of making a mobile full width/height div

> And when I click a button it swipes to the right revealing another div
> with new content, and pushing the current div to the left ( or right )

#### The blue box is my viewport, mobile in this case

Here's a crappy illustration to show what I mean
[image]

I have tried using CSS ( with semi-success ) I can reveal another div using

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}

#slide-options {
    background: #eee;
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

#slide-options.active {
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

But it's just sliding over the 1st div, not pushing it along
Any idea's or existing libraries?

Thank you!

Comment: It wouldn't push anything else, being absolutely-positioned. Got a demo or some HTML to show us?

Comment: my working version is cluttered with database connections so I can't really put anything online at the moment, will try to do so later. Why wouldn't you push any content? It's more obvious then just overlaying it with another div i think?

Comment: "It" wouldn't, not "I" wouldn't. Absolutely-positioned elements are outside document flow and don't typically affect other elements. You'd have to animate all your panels individually.

Comment: Create a simple demo so we can help. Otherwise the question is off-topic. http://jsfiddle.net